# is there a way to programmatically prevent certain mac address from accessing my web application

Tags: asp.net, security, networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

i am using windows server 2003 and 2008

i am about to install a web application on a server that is connected to other computers using **simple wired network** i.e. no active directory, no domain controller etc..

my question is:

is there a way to prevent mac addresses outside my specified list from accessing my application ? should it be through IIS or Web.config or should i put certain code in the page load events.

another concern: if i use an SSL to secure my application, is it enough along with a reputable anti virus to prevent a virus to access my server through any network computer using my web application

Comment: What kind of security will this give you?  Anyone with the ability to break into your network is probably going to know how to spoof their MAC address, and watching ARP and NetBIOS traffic will be enough to gather a working MAC address.  You would be better off using a proper authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

If you visualise the route from the client to your server; along this route there are 'hops', *i.e.*, routers and switches which route the client's request down one of multiple paths.

At each hop a different MAC address is inserted into the packet - this is the MAC address of the next hop on the route.

So although the IP address always stays the same throughout the entire route (hence you can use the server variables or such like to determine the client's IP address) the MAC that you receive at the server after the final hop is actually the MAC address of the last networking device that the request was directed through.

The only way you'd be able to accurately use this MAC address for some sort of access control is if you had no routing or switching hardware between you and all the clients.

Answer (score 4):

What if routing is involved - the MAC address you'd like to exclude is on another network? In that case you'll never see the MAC address. Using IIS you CAN filter specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to secure a network (also minimum requirement, else considered non-secure network)

1-get CISCO switches and router or (multilayer switch)

2-change native VLAN then create and configure VLANs for example 10, 20, 30 and put ranges of IP for each VLAN

3-enable port security: set max number of mac addresses and enable MAC address "sticky"

4-configure routing protocol to allow switches to "talk" to each other

good luck

Comment: What you've explained here is how to configure network security, whereas mokokamello's question asked how to configure a MAC access list for a web app on a server - not even security to the server, just to that web app. As far as I'm aware, no amount of Cisco switches can do this. Also, regarding point 4, why would you use a routing protocol on a switch? Routing protocols operate at layer 3; switches operate at layer 2. What you should do in that circumstance is enable STP on the switches, or a routing protocol on your routers.

Comment: @awj you are right, and i did not say that it is possible, i just gave my recommendations to secure a network in general. regarding point 4 "configure routing protocol to allow switches " i said to allow switches, not ON switches.

Comment: i think awj answer is the most appropriate answer, so mokokamello please accept awj answer